# VSCode w/ Remote connection and pyODBC: Windows SQL Server Authentication not working

Tags: python, sql-server, vscode-remote

I am using VSCode with an SSH remote connection to another Windows machine.

I am trying to connect to a database on the network.

If I log into that machine directly (outside of VScode), load my conda environment and run the script, it connects without issue to th MS SQL Server using integrated windows authentication.

However, when I am running remotely through VSCode, the Database connection returns:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Running whoami from the VScode terminal under conda gives me the proper username.  But running the python script gives the ANON error.

So is the remote server running python in a slightly different environment?  Is it launching the python interpreter as a generic user (under the server user and not the terminal user?)

Comment: Sounds like a Kerberos double-hop issue. You need to configure SPNs correctly, and you need to allow either Constrained Delegation or Resource Based Delegation (the latter is a little more secure), and your local machine, as well as the intermediate server and the SQL Server all need to be joined to the domain.